# A function $ f : [0,1] \to \Bbb{C} $ is differentiable with derivative 0, is constant.

Tags: proof-explanation

In Conway's complex analysis while proving proposition 2.10

"If $G$ is an open connected set and  $ f : G \to \Bbb{C} $ such that $f'(z)=0 \ \forall z \in G$ then f is constant"

He fixes some $z_{0} \in G$ and defines the set $A=$ {$z \in G: f(z)=f(z_0)$} and shows that this set is both open as well as closed, since it is a non-empty subset of a connected set, we have, $A=G$ which would complete the proof.

I can't understand the proof to show it's open, where he defines $ g(t)=f(zt+(1-t)a) \ , t \in [0,1]$ for some fixed $a \in A $ and $\epsilon >0$ such that $z\in B(a,\epsilon)\subset G$ He wants to show that $B(a,\epsilon) \subset A.$

By proving
$g'(t)=0 \ $on  $ [0,1]$ he concludes that g is constant.

I thought this result was only true for real valued functions. I am clear about everything else, why the function has been constructed in this way and all. I am just not able to convince myself of the above conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $g:[0,1]\to \mathbb  C$ is differentiable and $g'=0$ for all $t$ then  its real and imaginary parts are constants (because there derivatives are also $0$) , right? That proves that $g$ is a complex constant.

Comment: Okay, to clarify, we observe $g(t): [0,1] \to \Bbb{R}^2$ where if $g(t)=u(t)+i v(t)$ then $g'(t)=u'(t)+iv'(t) \implies u $ and $ v$ are constant.